# HTML CSS Responsive paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, tags, paragraph, responsive

I am designing a webpage and I am almost finished but there is a small issue that I can't seem to figure out.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        * {margin:0; padding:0; text-indent:0; }

        .float-box-footer{display:inline-block;position:relative;height:37px;background-color:#accb32;max-width: 860px;width: auto\9;}

        .p4{font-size: 12pt; color: black; padding-left:5pt; left:0; top:7pt; font-family:National, Arial, sans-serif;position:relative;}

        .p5{font-size: 7pt; color: black; padding-left:465pt;}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class='float-box-footer'>
    <p class="p4">Learn more <a href="http://www.google.com" alt="" >Google.com</a>
    </p>

    <p class="p5">© 2016 Google Google of Google. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

When you run the code it shows the green bar with text in it. When you resize the web page width wise the green bar shrinks along with the webpage and stays the proper size. However, the text in the far right does not do that. Once you go so far over it goes out of view and starts wrapping. I need the text to move along with the green bar.

I am stuck on this part and can not seem to figure it out. Can you anyone please help me out on what I am not doing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the green bar to respond to the width of the browser window, I would set your width on `.float-box-footer` to something like 100%. A percentage value will adjust with the window.

The problem you're facing now is that the width of `.float-box-footer` is being defined by the children elements inside there. The padding value on `.p5` is forcing the green box open. If you give `.float-box-footer` a fluid width value like 100% and throw a `text-align: right;` or `float: right;` onto `.p5` you should be in business.

I'd suggest reading up on the fundamentals of the CSS box model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Comment: That helped so much. Thank you very much I appreciate the response. The other problem I am having is resizing the left paragraph once it reaches a certain point on the screen. I have seen the media queries as the only way to do that but I never can seem to make that work. Do you have any suggestions on the resizing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer the code

```
* {margin:0; padding:0; text-indent:0; }

.float-box-footer{height:37px;background-color:#accb32;max-width: 860px;width: auto\9;}

.p4{font-size: 12pt; color: black; padding-left:5pt; left:0; top:7pt; font-family:National, Arial, sans-serif;position:relative; width:50%;}

.p5{font-size: 7pt; color: black; width:50%; text-align:right; float: right;}


<div class='float-box-footer'>
    <p class="p4">Learn more <a href="http://www.google.com" alt="" >Google.com</a>
    </p>

    <p class="p5">© 2016 Google Google of Google. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    * {margin:0; padding:0; text-indent:0; }

    .float-box-footer{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        height:37px;
        background-color:#accb32;
        max-width: 860px;
        width: auto\9;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }

    .p4{
        font-size: 12pt; 
        color: black; 
        padding-left:5pt; 
        left:0; top:7pt; 
        font-family:National, Arial, sans-serif;
        position:relative;}

    .p5{
        font-size: 7pt; 
        color: black; 
        padding-left:465pt;         
        }

</style>
```

Add a whitespace property with a no wrap value to the floatboxfooter div.
Check the floatboxfooter properties in my example. Hope this helps.